# PostgreSQL missing operator when using IN predicate with string array

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

Given this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tags
(
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  tagname TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  authorid int NOT NULL,
  created timestamp NOT NULL,
  lastmodified timestamp NOT NULL,

  constraint fk_authorid_tags foreign key(authorid) references users(id)
);
```

Why does the following query fails with the error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = text[]
LINE 2: select * from tags where tagname in ('{"c#","c"}'::text[])
```

Query:

```
select * from tags where tagname in ('{"c#","c"}'::text[])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IN` must contain a literal list, e.g.

```
tagname IN ('c#', 'c')
```

If you want an array, you must use `= ANY`:

```
tagname = ANY (ARRAY['c#', 'c'])
```

The error is arising because `tagname IN (somearray)` is interpreted as the query "is `tagname` equal to any element of the the 1-element list `(somearray)`". That means testing `tagname` for equality against `somearray`, the only element. As there's no `=` operator to compare `text` and `text[]`, this fails.

By contrast, `= ANY` says "For any element of the array on the right hand side, is the left hand operand equal to the element?". So it works.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation Craig.